# When using (nominal) categorical data, is a classifier needed? Or is knowing the distribution enough?

Tags: classification, density-function

I am working with 2 categorical variables associated with the condition of an animal as it goes into an animal control facility, and the outcome of the intervention. There are 6 types of intake conditions and 9 types of outcomes, so I started modeling with 2 discrete random variables

$X$: Intake Type {Abandoned, Euthanasia Request,...}, and $Y$: Outcome Type {Adoption, Died, Disposal,...}.

I have about 37,000 rows of data (one row for each intake/intervention) so I calculated the empirical probability mass function (pmf):

[image: empirical pmf]

Now let's suppose a new animal comes in. Given its condition, does it make sense to build a decision tree to classify the outcome?

Or would a calculation such as "given $X=x$, find the value $y$ which maximizes $P(\{Y=y\} \cap \{X=x\})$" provide an equivalently good answer? It just seems that if I have the pmf, it's easy to say that, for example, if the animal was an 'owner surrender' ($X=\mbox{owner surrender})$ then the best guess of the outcome is $Y=\mbox{transfer}$ since $P(\{Y=\mbox{transfer}\} \cap \{X=\mbox{owner surrender}\})$ is the largest probability ($0.189905$) in that column. It seems that a decision tree is not really needed for this problem.

Comment: For many problems there are classifiers that are better than trees, and what you propose here based on the distribution is actually also a classifier (i.e., a rule that states where to classify an object given X, namely here maximum (posterior) probability). So yes, a classifier is needed for classification, but the one you propose looks fine (in fact it may depend on details such as your loss function whether a better one can be found).

Comment: As you have only one input variable, which is in addition categorically, I don't think a decision tree makes much sense. As you point out, you have the pmf, that is $p(y,x)$, which together with the marginal $p(x)$ allows you to calculate the conditional probability $p(y|x)=\frac{p(y,x)}{p(x)}$. The best prediction is then the maximum probability, which is the maximum of the pmf for a given $x$. You could use a cost function for the different $y$s, which could change the optimal decision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you [Christian Hennig](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/247165/christian-hennig) and [K. Hencken](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/216782/k-hencken) for your comments. I will try to combine your insights into this answer, but if you wish to answer directly please feel free to do so and I will accept your answer.

Finding the value of $y$ which maximizes $P(\{Y=y\}\cap\{X=x\})$ given $x$ is a useful classifier for this problem. In fact, the proposed classifier is called a Maximum A Posteriori (MAP) classifier. A decision tree for this problem would probably not make too much sense. Answering the question 'is there a better classifier for this problem?' would first require defining a different loss function. For example, if the $y$s are assigned different weights, the optimal decision may be different from the current answer.